# Accessing a list from app web throws access denied

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, jsom

There is a Access Denied error being thrown when I try to access a list from the host web from the app web. The app has read access to the entire site collection. Why is it throwing this error?

```
"use strict";
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var hostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
var hostContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
var web = hostContext.get_web()
//var lists = web.get_lists();
var BlogURL = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("BlogURL"));
var PostLimit = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("PostLimit"));
var BackgroundColor = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("BackgroundColor"));

window.Communica = window.Communica || {};

//var app = angular.module('blogPart', []);

$(document).ready(function () {
    Communica.Part.init();

    var scriptbase = hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
     function () {
         $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
             function () {
                 $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.UserProfiles.js',
                    function () {
                        $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', execCrossDomainRequest);
                    });
             });
     });
});

function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params;
    var strParams;

    params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    strParams = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    var context;
    var factory;
    var appContextSite;
    var mylist;
    var today = new Date();
    var todayString = today.toString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var BlogTitle = BlogURL;
    if (BlogURL[BlogTitle.trim().length - 1] == "/") {
        BlogTitle = BlogURL.substring(0, BlogTitle.length - 1);
    }
    if (BlogTitle.indexOf("/") > -1) {
        var x = "/" + BlogTitle.split(/[/ ]+/).pop();
        if (x.indexOf(".") > -1) {
            BlogTitle = BlogTitle.substring(0, BlogTitle.lastIndexOf("/"));
        }
    }
    if (BlogTitle.indexOf("/sites/") > -1) {
        BlogTitle = BlogTitle.substring(BlogTitle.lastIndexOf("/sites/"), BlogTitle.length);
    }
    context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, BlogTitle);
    this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
    mylist = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('Posts');
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Leq><FieldRef Name="PublishedDate"/><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">'+todayString+'</Value></Leq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="PublishedDate" Ascending="FALSE" /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>'+PostLimit+'</RowLimit></View>');
    var collListItem = mylist.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(mylist);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
         Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
         Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the permissions set correctly in the AppManifest.xml I needed to have site read and have the app-only check-box unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your *context* is the problem, specifically the SPAppWebUrl that you're using from the query strings includes the App path, so http://[appurl]/site/siteappisinstalled/AppName/ which results in your get_lists() call looking for the site under /site/siteappisinstalled/AppName/ and not /site/siteappisinstalled/. (Is that why you're using ProxyWebRequestFactory to get the web?)

Try something like this (working example to create an item in a list):

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(getQueryStrings().SPAppWebUrl.replace('[AppName]',''));
var oList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('PV5Projektdata');
var itemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreationInfo);
oListItem.set_item('Title', 'List item title');
oListItem.update();
context.load(oListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (){
    alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());        
}), Function.createDelegate(this, function (ctx, args){        
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}));
```

Note the [AppName] in the replace.

Hope that helps.

Comment: getQueryStrings() is undefined. What is it supposed to be referenced to?

Comment: Oh yes that is a helper method to get the query strings as an object so we can do the string replace easily..